# View between two views android XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I need to display an image between a card and a background of an activity. Sample image is attached. I am struggling with layouts so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#D3E6ED"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Image is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use this library for the circular image. This code will resolve your problem.

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

> Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f36121">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="24dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Login" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                    android:text="Sign In" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:src="@mipmap/template_icon"
            app:civ_border_color="#f36121"
            app:civ_border_width="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/card_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1):

Put the card and the imageview in the same place, but add top margin on the card equal to half the image view height.  And put the image view second in the xml, so that it goes on top in the z ordering.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is some near output. Only you need to change cardview shape as you want.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D3E6ED">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:translationZ="@dimen/_90sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/current_location" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_camera"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:tint="@color/black"
        android:translationZ="@dimen/_90sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_icon_camera_attendant" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```